# Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.DBNull'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I try to apply left outer join on the basis of two ids one in the primary key of one table while the foreign key of another table also nullable

```
  var yarnPOFilter_Grid = (from yrq in _context.Yarn_Requisition_Details
                                 //join ypo in 
  _context.Yarn_PurchaseOrder_Details on yrq.YarnRequsitionDetailID 
 equals 
  ypo.YarnRequsitionDetailID into t
                                   join ypo in 
  _context.Yarn_PurchaseOrder_Details on yrq.YarnRequsitionDetailID 
  equals 
  DBNull.Value.Equals(ypo.YarnRequsitionDetailID) ? 0 : 
  ypo.YarnRequsitionDetailID into t
                                 from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty() // 
  DefaultIfEmpty preserves left-hand elements that have no matches on the 
  right side 
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     YarnRequsitionDetailID = 
  (rt.YarnRequsitionDetailID == null ? long.MinValue : 
  rt.YarnRequsitionDetailID),
                                     yrq.YarnID,
                                     yrq.Yarn.YarnName,
                                     yrq.YarnFellowID,
                                     yrq.Yarn_FellowCodes.YarnFellowCode,
                                     yrq.QuantityRequired,
                                     rt.QuantityOrdered,
                                     QuantityBalance_Custom = 
   yrq.QuantityRequired - rt.QuantityOrdered
                                 }).ToList();
        return yarnPOFilter_Grid;
```

I get this error message when I deal with null in joining condition 
Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.DBNull'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `ToList()` First before `Select` as there is no sql equivalent to the conditions you added in the `YarnRequsitionDetailID = (rt.YarnRequsitionDetailID == null ? long.MinValue : rt.YarnRequsitionDetailID)`

so it will be

`from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()).ToList().Select(c => new
                                 {
                                     YarnRequsitionDetailID = 
                                     (c.rt.YarnRequsitionDetailID == null ? long.MinValue : 
                                     c.rt.YarnRequsitionDetailID),
                                     c.yrq.YarnID,
                                     c.yrq.Yarn.YarnName,
                                     c.yrq.YarnFellowID,
                                     c.yrq.Yarn_FellowCodes.YarnFellowCode,
                                     c.yrq.QuantityRequired,
                                     c.rt.QuantityOrdered,
                                     QuantityBalance_Custom = 
                                     c.yrq.QuantityRequired - c.rt.QuantityOrdered
                                 }).ToList();`

i hope this solved your previous problem

Comment: .Select give error 
An expression of type 'method group' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.

Comment: edited my answer, just play around with the value of `c` in `Select(c => `

Comment: Error on last .tolist()
 An expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#2>' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.